# How can I specify the spring-data-mongodb version using spring-boot?

Tags: mongodb, maven, pom.xml, spring-boot

I want to use the latest version of spring-data-mongodb, in order to use the full text search feature, but I don't know how I can specify this using the spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb dependence.

You can read here: [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/1.1.7.RELEASE) that the spring-data-mongodb version is not specify.

This is my pom file:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Boot Rest -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Boot Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring MongoDB integration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: First I suggest upgrading to Spring Boot 1.1.7 and then simply add a property `spring-data-releasetrain.version` and set that to the latest version. `Evans-RELEASE` I believe. Although you might be aware that things might break as Spring Boot 1.1.x hasn't been tested with the latest versions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring Boot defines all its dependencies and dependency versions in the [spring-boot-dependencies](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-dependencies) project. This project only contains a [pom](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml) with only dependencies and versions as properties.

Spring Data releases all of its compatible releases in a so called release train and this makes sure that all dependencies of that version will work together.

When you take [a closer look a the pom](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L110) you will see a maven property named `spring-data-releasetrain.version` and for the upcoming Spring Boot 1.2 it points to the latest release train version `Evans-RELEASE`. The 1.1.7 version points to the previous version `Dijkstra-SR4`. I would suggest an upgrade from 1.1.6 to 1.1.7 just in case.

You're project already has the `spring-boot-starter-parent` project as its parent so in theory upgrading the Spring Data versions should be as easy as overriding the specified property.

```
<properties>
    <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Evans-RELEASE</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
</properties>
```

As mentioned earlier the use of the release train is preferred as this will make sure you get all the compatible versions.

Comment: Its not working. Currently i see the releasetrain-version as, `Hopper-BUILD-SNAPSHOT`. When i added in pom.xml, i'm getting error saying: `Project build error: Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain:pom:Hopper-BUILD-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: When using snapshots you will have to add the snapshot repositories to your pom file as well. Those aren't available in the central maven repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can find that mongodb dependency in the parent project pom file

```
/../.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.3.0.RELEASE.pom
```

That file defines all the dependency version for other libs SpringBoot use

```
<properties>
    <activemq.version>5.15.12</activemq.version>
    <antlr2.version>2.7.7</antlr2.version>
    ...
    <mongodb.version>4.0.3</mongodb.version>
    ...
</properties>
```

So if you want to use different version for mongodb, define a properties in your pom file to override the default one like (I think this will only work if you use `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent )

```
<properties>
    <mongodb.version>3.11.2</mongodb.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @sendon1982 worked for me.  Here is an example of my POM.XML.  I am adding it as an answer here because I could not paste in my pom file as a comment to sendon1982 answer...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>test.barry</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>test.barry.Main</start-class>
        <mongodb.version>4.1.0</mongodb.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```